# QtConcurrent::run how to stop background task

Tags: multithreading, qt, concurrency, qmainwindow

I have the same situation like this: [stop thread started by qtconcurrent::run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845579/stop-thread-started-by-qtconcurrentrun)

I need to close child thread (started with QtConcurrent::run) on closeEvent in QMainWindow.
But my function in child thread use code from *.dll: I can`t use loop because all that I do - is calling the **external** dll like

```
QFuture<void> = QtConcurrent::run(obj->useDllfunc_with_longTermJob());
```

And when I close the app with x-button my gui is closed, but second thread with_longTermJob() still worked and when is finished I have an error.
I know some decisions for this:

1. using other functions like map() or something else with
   QFuture.cancel/stop functionality, not QtConcurrent::run().But I need only one function call. run() is what I need.
2. or use QThread instead Concurrent.But it`s not good for me.

What method more simple and better and how can I implement this? Is there a method that I don`t listed?
Could you provide small code sample for decision. Thx!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952474/non-blocking-worker-interrupt-file-copy?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QtConcurrent::run` isn't a problem here. You must have means of stopping the `dllFuncWithLongTermJob`. If you don't have such means, then the API you're using is broken, and you're out of luck. There's nothing you can do that'd be generally safe. Forcibly terminating a thread can leave the heap in an inconsistent state, etc. - if you need to terminate a thread, you need to immediately abort the application.

Hopefully, you can call something like `stopLongTermJob` that sets some flag that interrupts the `dllFuncWithLongTermJob`.

Then:

```
auto obj = new Worker;
auto objFuture = QtConcurrent::run([=]{obj->dllFuncWithLongTermJob();});
```

To interrupt:

```
obj->stopLongTermJob(); // must be thread-safe, sets a flag
objFuture.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: Actually there is something the OP might do, but it all depends on what the DLL does. If dllFuncWithLongTermJob is just a stateless run-once-and-forget-about-it kind of function, then it could be run in a child process, which could be killed without serious consequences for the main program. That's just using the OS to do the cleanup work. Needless to say, this is a last resort solution that I would only use for lack of a properly interruptible alternative.

Comment: @odelande There's way more to the benefit of running it in a separate process. The OS cleanup is one part, certainly. The other important part is that the dll won't corrupt *your* state when it gets abruptly terminated. Running it in a child process is an excellent idea, in fact!

Comment: If I understood correctly - I need to use QThread instead QtConcurrent for control child thread? Concurrent doesn`t useful in this situation? At that moment I just implement closeEvent in MainWindow for waiting dialog if child threads count != 0x00.